# Update Join Attributes by Location

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, update

I have a shapefile with points, and a shapefile with polygons. 
I want to sum the attribute value of all points that are contained in a polygon, and I'd like to do this for each polygon in my dataset. 
I succeeded to do that with Join Attributes by Location but what I want is that when I modify the polygons, the attribute values must be updated.

Can anyone help me?